# TYPO3 - Extbase extension won't render record information after upgrade from 7LTS to 8LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

After upgrading from 7LTS to 8LTS my extension won't render all record information. It looks like the query is running though. I used to render this table in my list view:

List.html

```
<tbody>                                 
    <f:for each="{records}" as="record">                        
        <tr id="{record.uid}">
            <td>{record.uid}</td>
            <td class="name"><f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record}">{record.name}</f:link.action></td>
        </tr>
    </f:for>
    </f:if>                 
</tbody>
```

With the following Action in CodeController.php

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @param integer $minUid
 * @param integer $maxUid
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {

    $this->view->assign('records', $this->codeRepository->findUidRange($minUid,$maxUid));

}
```

I get this now:

```
</tbody>                                    
    <tr id="1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="legal-name"><a href="code/2138/"></a></td>
    </tr>                       
    <tr id="1">
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="legal-name"><a href="code/2549/"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Solved: ... the problem was that I had TCA definitions in ext_tables.php. Now moved to Configuration/TCA/ ... and it's working again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug the records in the fluid template:

`<f:debug>{records}</f:debug>`

What do you see?

Take a look at your domain model and see if the getters and setters are there for "name". Also check your TCA to see if the definition for the field "name" is correct.

Comment: I always forget about f:debug ... please find the result of the first two records ... shouldn't I see any values in there?

Comment: What do you mean? The debug should list the records, so you should see all the values in there.

Comment: But there are empty as you can see above. What might causes this? Has there been changes from 7LTS ot 8LTS?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your debug code above. Is it possible that you have your TCA definition in ext_tables.php? Since 8 the TCA definitions should be in Configuration/TCA/

Comment: As RIVATI said, did you add the functions getName and setName to your model?

Comment: @RIVATI ... yes, I'm afraid I still have them in there ... see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845119/typo3-tca-in-ext-tables-php-check-for-v8 ... I tried to get this fixed first now

Comment: @PaulBeck: yes, they are set (see above comment)

Comment: @RIVATI: Ok ... the problem was that I still had TCA definitions in ext_tables.php. Now moved to Configuration/TCA/ ... and it's working again. Thanks