# TYPO3 - TCA in ext_tables.php check and TCA/Overrides for v8

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

Updated ext_tables.php, TCA and TCA/Overrides for TYPO3 8LTS? I moved the TCA definitions from ext_tables.php to /TCA folder and the query in list view is working again:

ext_tables.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {die('Access denied.');}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Code',
    'Description'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('tx_code_domain_model_code', 'EXT:code/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_tx_code_domain_model_code.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_code_domain_model_code');
```

Configuration/TCA/tx_code_domain_model_code.php

```
... // TCA defintions
```

Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {die('Access denied.');}

$_EXTKEY = 'code';

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Code',
    'Description'
);

$extensionName = strtolower(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY)); 
$pluginName = strtolower('Code'); 
$pluginSignature = $extensionName.'_'.$pluginName; 
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform'; 
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_code.xml');
```

Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {die('Access denied.');}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('code', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Description');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not compatible.

You should do your TCA definition of tx_code_domain_model_code in:
Configuration/TCA/tx_code_domain_model_code.php

The static template definition in:
Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php

And your plugin and flexform definition in: Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

Be aware that the $_EXTKEY variable is not defined in those files so you have to type the extension key yourself.

Comment: Wrap your code with call_user_func(function () { ... });
Have a look at https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/styleguide/

Comment: @jokumer although it's good practice, what do you mean with this solution? It doesn't solve the incompatible ext_tables.php or the lack of $_EXTKEY

Comment: Just good practice, to declare variables inside the function scope rather than globally. See https://usetypo3.com/good-practices-in-extensions.html

Comment: @RIVATI: Which are the static template defintions? I moved the $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_code_domain_model_code'] = array('ctrl' ... to Configuration/TCA/... and it was working again. But when I also move the plugin and flexform definition to: Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php ... I get the above error ... how does it need to look like?

Comment: @PhilippM the static file definition is the line with "addStaticFile". And like I said the $_EXTKEY variable is not defined in the Configuration/TCA folder so you'll have to replace that variable with your extension key

Comment: @RIVATI: Ah ok ... I updated accordingly. Thanks for the help on this ... looks like all is working again.